# How to track a log file in TCL

Tags: linux, logging, tcl, tail

Say there is a file `log.txt` and some kind of log is being appended to it permanently.

I want to track that file in the TCL environment.

I have tried this but it didn't worked.

```
set log [open log.txt a]

for { } { true } { update; after 1000 } {

    # expected to get here the appended part
    read $log

    seek $log 0 end

}
```

Is it possible to read the modified file by the same file handle `log`, or I have to close and re-open the file `log.txt` ?

Is there a kind of equivalent of Linux command `tail -f` in TCL ?

Comment: May be this can help - `http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65437-tail-a-file/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `tail`.  It knows more that you about how to handle complicated cases (you can look at its source).

In one of my projects, I have something like this to monitor a trace file produced by a proprietary tool:

```
set fd [open [list | tail --follow=name --retry --lines 0 $opt(trace) 2>@1]]
chan event $fd readable [list FollowTrace $fd]

proc FollowTrace fd {
  if {[gets $fd line] < 0} {
    set code [catch {close $fd} err]
    if {$code == 0} {
      set ::result 0
    } else {
      puts stderr $err
      set ::result 1
    }
    return
  }

  switch -regexp -matchvar parts -- $line {
    {Tm_Session::Open.*FileName=([^,]+)} {
       TryMakeLock [FullPathname [lindex $parts 1]]
     }
     {Tm_Session::Close.*FileName=([^,]+)} {
        StartUpload [lindex $parts 1]
     }
  }
}
```

The general idea is that you spawn `tail` on a given file then enter event loop and process `tail`'s output line-by-line.

Comment: While leveraging other tools is generally a great way to do things, your solution takes more code and requires an external program than just implementing a pure tcl solution.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, I honestly invite you to peer into the GNU tail sources to find out that the task of watching a file being appended externally is not as easy task as it seems te be on the first glance. Sure it can be done using Tcl (provided you first pull a relevant fcntl() call into the script level), but then why?

Comment: Even if you need the -follow=name functionality, it's not too hard to do in Tcl - eg. see my [Flog](http://wiki.tcl.tk/29120).

Answer (score 0):

You're not far off, just a few things to fix:

1. In this code you are reading from the file, not appending to it, some other process will be doing that, so should open the file in read mode, not append mode, ie. drop the "a" option from the open command.
2. You should only seek to the end of the file once, before you start reading, otherwise you will be skipping stuff that gets added later, so move the seek command ahead of the loop.
3. In the code posted, you are not doing anything with the text that you read - I'll give an example of just writing it back to  stdout.
4. You only need the update command if your processing within the loop involves updating a gui or something else that requires the event loop - it's not needed for the code posted.
   Altogether this gives:

   ```
   set log [open log.txt]
   seek $log 0 end

   for { } { true } { after 1000 } {

       # expected to get here the appended part
       puts -nonewline [read $log]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to write `tail -f` equivalent on pure Tcl. The code is below:

```
proc readHandler {handle} {
    puts -nonewline [read $handle]
    flush stdout
    # to reduce CPU overhead...
    after 1000
}

set hFile [open "file.log" "r"]
# seek to the end of file if needed
# seek $hFile 0 end 

fconfigure $hFile -buffering none -eofchar "" -blocking no
fileevent $hFile readable [subst {readHandler $hFile}]

#just for exiting into main event loop
vwait forever
```

Comment: I think you'll find that the file always appears readable when you're at its end, so the handler fires continuously and chews up all your cpu uselessly.

Comment: Ok. Then you always can insert sleep command (i.e. `after 1000`) into handler to reduce CPU overhead.